# OpenGL/glsl : Preprocessor issue with specific directive

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, c-preprocessor

I'm having issue with a very specific directive in my glsl shader.

I would like to use a directive like that:

```
#if defined(numDirectionalLights) && (numDirectionalLights > 0)
struct DirectionalLight
{
vec3 color;
vec3 direction;
};
uniform DirectionalLight u_dirLights[numDirectionalLights];
#endif
```

When I compile the glsl program, I get this error:

```
ERROR: 0:6: '' : syntax error: incorrect preprocessor directive
WARNING: 0:6: unexpected tokens following the preprocessor directive - expected a newline
```

You can see this error [here](http://shdr.bkcore.com/#1/5VLLbsIwEPyVVZBQUiGgKidQe2nVU1v11AtByI2dYBSvI8ehPMS/d+MkENL8QaU85J1Z7+zOnjyuo0IJtLk3X3qZEZHMpUZQgstCZRCnmtlFiCEOZAxcxBIF97FQL5K4lqgsfZPJxuYBDIfQi8ATTIMQc2uKyEIXDvEU4k5EDxDpVJtFfeANjQJneguUsTbqTzoUa6JWhZZ91VeUPBDISf5kAn2MsrsQwT07LTkoJtEPgHQBJOn61bDkudQGj0DaZv79eDqC6eVDx6BU6Y1aA9zQ1dfxMWuN/C6sANdcpnNZ99ZBkHpkaatfxWwTfWdE3d9iM1Cai/RLip9+ODN6W7V7wXfMHCQmVcH4o6l4G/68SvwP7rd8d5KgGQx5Xk1fHoXf9gHuaqD0HtxilL4Sv+MIEd3WNKZfFgauU6Ysgsf7w3FRL10b6VhIFxLZbdxq5Llq3rz65xNOy6pxvM298y8=).

It's strange because in C-Language, this syntax is allowed but there is more strange, the LibGDX Framework uses this syntax [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl#L153) and with LibGDX, it works! I have first thinked about an encoding error but my shaders are in UTF-8 and that's not the problem.

Do you know how to make this syntax works ?

Comment: Is this about OpenGL-ES or OpenGL? Which version do you supply in your shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL uses GLSL ES 1.0. Its [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) stipulates in Section 3.4 that:

> #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #elif, and #endif are defined to operate as for C++ except for the following:
>
> ...
>
> •
>   Undefined identifiers not consumed by the `defined` operator do not
>   default to '0'. Use of such identifiers causes an error.

The issue is that `numDirectionalLights` is an undefined identifier not consumed by the `defined` operator. In C++ (or C) that would have a value of 0. In GLSL ES its use is an error. Short-circuit evaluation is provided for by the spec but the compiler falters at parsing the line, even before evaluating the `#if defined` part of your line.

Either break your test into two:

```
#if defined(numDirectionalLights) 
#if (numDirectionalLights > 0)
```

... or else explicitly define `numDirectionalLights` as `0`.

Based on the assumption that LibGDX builds for full-fat OpenGL, there's a subtle distinction in [the spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.1.50.09.pdf): under ES it is an error for the programmer to use an undefined identifier on a line the preprocessor visits. In full-size OpenGL it is only an error to get the preprocessor to evaluate an #if clause containing an undefined identifier. Which, given short-circuit evaluation, is why the `#if defined(x) && ...` pattern works there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you are totally right! And I know why it works on LibGDX, I added the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reason why LibGDX shader works:

LibGDX prepends `#define` [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/DefaultShader.java#L631).

If `renderable.environment` is not null, then it add `#define numDirectionalLights XX` (it may be 0).

If `renderable.environment` is null , then `#define lightingFlag` is not added to the [shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl#L125) and `#if defined(numDirectionalLights) && (numDirectionalLights > 0)` is not called in the shader. It works well.

So we can see that in the LibGDX shader, it should be only `#if numDirectionalLights > 0` because `numDirectionalLights` must exists.